# Android Firebase Model Class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Model Class

```
public class Sell {


private String transactionID;
private int dollarPrice;
private boolean isInParts;
private String itemName;


public Sell() {
}


public Sell(String transactionID,
            int dollarPrice,
            boolean isInParts,
            String itemName) {

    this.transactionID = transactionID;
    this.dollarPrice = dollarPrice;
    this.isInParts = isInParts;
    this.itemName = itemName;
}


public String getTransactionID() {
    return transactionID;
}

public int getDollarPrice() {
    return dollarPrice;
}

public boolean isInParts() {
    return isInParts;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}



public void setTransactionID(String transactionID) {
    this.transactionID = transactionID;
}

public String getSellingString() {
    String string = "I want to Sell "+DOLLAR_SIGN+dollarPrice+ " "+itemName;

        if (isInParts) {
            string +=  " in Parts";
            // I want to sell $100 Goods in Parts
        }
    }
    return string;
  }
}
```

When i commit it to firebase
with the following parameters

> transactionId = "6475xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
>   dollarPrice = 100 
>   inParts = true
>   itemName = "Goods"

i get the following in my firebase dashboard

```
{
 "dollarPrice" : 100,
 "inParts" : true,
 "itemName" : "Goods",
 "transactionID" : "6475xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

but in my recycler view's view holder i have a text view which i set the following text

```
textview.setText(sell.getSellingString());
```

my textView always displays

> I want to sell $100 Goods

Instead of

> I want to sell $100 Goods in Parts

Thereby neglecting the boolean value i specified.

How can i get Around this?

Answer (score 1):

This 
=> [Firebase won't bind boolean value to field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624403/firebase-wont-bind-boolean-value-to-field/37625222)

Answered my question.

When trying to get a boolean

```
 private boolean up;
 public boolean isUp() {
    return up;
 }
```

> if your boolean field is named ***isUp***, then the getter must be named **isIsUp()** or **getIsUp()**. Alternatively, if you want a getter named **isUp**, the field name would be **up**.