# Kotlin funtions return value is getting saved in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am facing weird issue I have kotlin class like below

```
class RequestCenterDetails : Serializable{
var instituteId: String? = null
var centerId: String? = null
var centerKey: String? = null
var instituteKey: String? = null
var studentId: String? = null
var studentUID: String? = null
var studentFullName: String? = null
var studentEmailId: String? = null
var status: String? = null
var requestTime: Long? = null
var grantTime: Long? = null
var grantUserUID: String? = null
var grantUserEmailID: String? = null
var rejectComment: String? = null
var grantUserName: String? = null
var active: Boolean? = null

var instituteName: String? = null
var centerAddress: String? = null
var centerLocation: GeoPoint? = null

 // this function return value is getting stored in firebase
 fun isActiveRequest() : Boolean {
   return  active ?: false
}
}
```

and this is how i am saving into firebase

```
DatabaseReference requestRef = studentAccessRequestRef.child("/" + appfirebaseUserId + "/" + requestDetails.getCenterKey());
    requestRef.setValue(requestDetails);
```

and this is how its store its return type

[image]

I want to know why it is storing function return value. #AskFirebase

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37514605/1524450) the Firebase Database SDK will serialize properties for which there is a JavaBean-style getter. `isActiveRequest` probably qualifies as such a getter, hence why its value is serialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `@Exclude` annotation to avoid that, otherwise Firebase SDK triggers that value to POJO object due to variable serialization.

Try something like following:

```
@Exclude
fun isActiveRequest(): Boolean = active ?: false
```

Comment: so using @Exclude is only the way to solve this?. What is the best practice to avoid such issue

Comment: @FaisalAhmed, Being that the only way, that is the best practice to solve that problem